# Call method in separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need to call class method in separate thread.  The method has a parameter and a return value.

**Details**

I have a Form with two TextBoxes.  User put value in the first TextBox and get the result in the second one:

```
 private void tbWord_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     tbResponce.Text = Wiki.DoWork(tbWord.Text);
 }
```

The Wiki-class must use Wikipedia API:

```
public class Wiki
{
    private class State
    {
        public EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public String result;
        public String word;
    }

    private static void PerformUserWorkItem( Object stateObject )
    {
        State state = stateObject as State;

        if(state != null)
        {
            Uri address = new Uri("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + state.word);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responce.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            state.result = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

            state.eventWaitHandle.Set(); 
        }
    }

    public static String DoWork(String _word)
    {
        State state = new State();
        state.word = _word;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PerformUserWorkItem, state);
        state.eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        return state.result;                   
    }     
}
```

*Problem*

When user press keys in the tbWord the main form freeze and wait while Wiki class do all the work.

How can I run DoWork asynchronously?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or use TPL like this:

```
private void tbWord_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
 { 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return Wiki.DoWrok(tbWord.Text);
    }).ContinueWith(taskState =>
    {
        tbResponce.Text = taskState.Result;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
 }
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx

Comment: If you can use .Net 4, then you should definitely use TPL (System.Threading.Tasks).  This will also allow you to track any pending tasks and cancel them easier.  

For instance, the user enters "abcd" into the text box and that fires off a task to the wiki.

Before that completes, the user enters "efgh".

If the "efgh" lookup completes *first*, then it will populate the results and these will be overwritten by the "abcd" search.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. This will allow you to run your operation asynchronously. You can then update your UI back on the Dispatcher thread when you get notified by the `BackgroundWorker` that it has completed the operation.

Comment: Why I can not place BackgroundWorker on my form (http://imagebin.org/199796)? WPF application.

Comment: Looking at your image, the `BackgroundWorker` component is listed as a WinForms component. If your in WPF, you may need a WinForms host in there somewhere. Alternately, just created it in the code behind. See [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) and related methods about how to asynchronously perform web requests. This would eliminate the need of any custom background processing.

Answer (score 0):

Youc can use WPF Dispatcher to execute operation in a Main UI thread , since you already using `WaitOne()` in `DoWork` - main DoWork operation would be synchronous so you can use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to push changes in UI thread asynchronously:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Input, 
        new ThreadStart(() => 
          { 
             tbResponce.Text = Wiki.DoWork(tbWord.Text); 
          }));
```

Please elt me know whether this works for you since Polity mentioned some possible synchronization issues

Answer (score 0):

Do not wait for the `ThreadPool` thread to complete in your UI thread, but subscribe to a complete event instead:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.DoWorkComplete += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
        program.DoWorkAsync();

        // Wait 10 seconds, worker thread should finish beforehand, so
        // you see console output
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    public event EventHandler<CompleteEventArgs> DoWorkComplete;

    public void DoWorkAsync()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            // Download data here
            string result = "Result from Wiki";

            if(DoWorkComplete != null)
                DoWorkComplete(this, new CompleteEventArgs(result));
        });
    }

    public class CompleteEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CompleteEventArgs(string result)
        {
            this.Result = result;
        }

        public string Result { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This is a console application. I can `WriteLine` from any thread. If you are working with WPF, you need to use `Dispatcher` to make sure you handle the `DoWorkComplete` event back in the UI-thread ([sll already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359297/17713)). If you are working with Windows Forms, you have to do the same with `Control.Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an async call to achieve just that,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582